# How do I get PostScript to accept relative windows filenames?

Tags: postscript

Relative filenames would greatly simplify use of PS code on USB, etc..

Absolute filenames need double reverse slshes such as

```
(C:\\Users\\MrDon\\Desktop\\gsPlay\\yourcode) (r) file
```

or this substitute Windows character

```
(C:/Users/MrDon/Desktop/gsPlay/yourcode) (r) file
```

It should be possible to just use `(\\yourcode)` or `(/yourcode)`

I seem to have gotten this to work once, but repeated attempts
produce a file not found error.

What am I doing wrong?

Reliable relative filenames would greatly simpliy coding and
remove the need for any particular ISP.

Comment: I'd suggest you read section 3.8.2 "Named Files" of the PostScript Language Reference Manual, the subject is too detailed to handle here. Basically though your filename has no device, all named files **should** start %device%. If you do not specify a device, then the available storage devices are searched until the operation succeeds or all devices have been searched without result. By convention interpreters running on an OS, eg Windows, use the %os% device and then you access files using OS-specific paths. But note that the **PostScript** device has no CWD so you must specify the full path